# 'Graphics' and 'GL' shown in meminfo only for application targeting 4.0 and above?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am profiling the memory usage for out application with meminfo. During the process, I got a interesting founding.

I created a tiny blank page activity with targeting API level = 14, loaded to a 4.4 device, found:

```html
                   Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap       40       40        0        0     5444     4816      135
  Dalvik Heap     1975     1536        0        0    36600    28452     8148
 Dalvik Other     1068      940        0        0
        Stack       60       60        0        0
    Other dev      700      636        4        0
     .so mmap     1642     1272        0        0
    .apk mmap       47        0        0        0
    .ttf mmap        2        0        0        0
    .dex mmap      318       20        8        0
   Other mmap        5        4        0        0
     Graphics    31520    31520        0        0    <----------------------
           GL    11464    11464        0        0    <----------------------
      Unknown      955      952        0        0
        TOTAL    49796    48444       12        0    42044    33268     8283
```

Later, if I changed the API level to 11, and profiled again:

```html
                   Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap       44       44        0        0     2968     2101        6
  Dalvik Heap     2042     1484        0        0    36600    28432     8168
 Dalvik Other     1098      932        0        0
        Stack       56       56        0        0
    Other dev        4        0        4        0
     .so mmap      694      556        0        0
    .apk mmap       47        0        0        0
    .ttf mmap        2        0        0        0
    .dex mmap      314       20        8        0
   Other mmap        5        4        0        0
      Unknown      429      420        0        0
        TOTAL     4735     3516       12        0    39568    30533     8174
```

There is no 'Graphics' and 'GL' at all. So, any idea of these two items? And what's reason that API level leads to different result 'TOTAL'.

Thanks all.